# Why was the information saved after the type erasure?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

```
class Generic<T> {
    void method(T t) {
        print(t.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
public class Program {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Generic<String> g = new Generic1<>();
        g.method(new String());
    }
}
```

As expected, the output is `String`. Why was the information about type saved if the type erasure was happened? If I understand it correctly, the output should have been `Object`.

Comment: At runtime `t` is defined, it has a type. Some reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens?rq=1

Comment: Passing in (or storing) an instance of a class is the classic way to get around type erasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with generics.

Each object [knows it class object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--). You are getting "String" as output because this simply is the runtime class of a string object (which - by the way - you are creating).

Answer (score 8):

For the same reason that this works:

```
            Object s = new String();
// Note ----^^^^^^
            System.out.println(s.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

The *object* still knows what it is and can tell us when we ask it via `getClass`.